# Hadoop:hadoop fs -put error MSG:[ There are 2 datanode(s) running and 2 node(s) are excluded in this operation.]

Tags: hadoop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJRcA.png)
I have installed  the hadoop 2.6.5,when i try to put file from local to hdfs ,there comes this Exception ,i don't know how to solve this problem !!need hlep...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a networking problem.  The client process (where you ran the `hdfs dfs -put` command) failed to connect to the DataNode hosts.  I can tell from the stack trace that at this point, you have already passed the point of interacting with the NameNode, so connectivity from client to NameNode is fine.

I recommend handling this as a basic network connectivity troubleshooting problem between client and all DataNode hosts.  Use tools like `ping` or `nc` or `telnet` to test connectivity.  If basic connectivity fails, then resolve it by fixing network configuration.

Comment: But my ssh is fine? I can ssh between master and  slaves just fine!why there  is any networking problem.

Thanks a lot ,i will have a try...

Comment: fininally ,found the error!                     I didn't stop centos firewalld service which includes the datanode can't  communicate with namenode!!!!

check firewalld status:systemctl status firewalld

 if the result is active 
 use:
       systemctl stop firewalld
      systemctl disable firewalld

Comment: Nice job finding the problem!